# How to check size file CSV export by jQuery Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, datatable, datatables

I'm doing the CSV export function with Datatables, but now I want to check if the file size is greater than 1MB, I won't export the file.

But I don't know how to do it, hope someone will know or have done a check on CSV file size Datatables. 
This is my current code:

```
var otable =  $table.DataTable({
        "scrollX": true,
        "ordering": false,
        language: lg_opt,
        data: data_json,
        columns: [
            { title: "No", data: "No" },
            { title: "Name", data: "Name" },
            { title: "Data", data: "Data" },
        ],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
        {
                filename: 'Report_'+d+'_'+i,
                extend: 'csv',
                title: 'Report,
                bom: true,
                customize: function ( csv ) {
                    var split_csv = csv.split("\n");
                    split_csv.splice(0, 1);
                    csv = split_csv.join("\n");
                    return csv;
                }
        }
        ],
        "bDestroy": true,
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont know if it possible or not but you may do server side check, on clicking export, generate a csv file in your project directory, then check its size, if size greater than 1.1 MB delete it showing users an alert, else download it .

Comment: @iamawesome Thanks for your ideas!